# Population change and total fatalities (Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$, Coyote Gulch excercise $8.28.28$)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem statement $8.28.28$ is as follows:

- The initial population is 365.
- If there would be no accidental deaths, the population would have grown by a factor of $e$.
- The accidental deaths are 1 victim per day among every 100 citizens.

We need to find the population at given time $t$ and cumulative number of fatalities at a given time $t$ (where $t$ is in years, and it is assumed that each year has 365 days).

If $f(x)$ is the population, where $x$ is days, we can express the differential equation as:

$f'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{365} - \frac{f(x)}{100} = -\frac{265}{36500}f(x)$

Its solution is: $f(x) = 365 e^{-\frac{2.65}{365}x}$, where $x$ is in days. Or $y = g(t) = 365 e^{-2.65t} = f(365t)$, where $t$ is in years (i.e. $x = 365t$). So far so good, and it agrees with the answer in the book.

However, when it comes to the cumulative number of fatalities, I don't know why I could not approach it as follows. Namely, that is just the sum of all fatalities from day 0 to day x. The number of fatalities on each day $x$ is $\frac{f(x)}{100}$, so the cumulative number after $x$ days is $\sum_{i=0}^x {\frac{f(i)}{100}}$. If we introduced a step function $s(x)$ to be the number of fatalities that happened on day $x$, then we get $\sum_{i=0}^x {\frac{f(i)}{100}} = \sum_{i=0}^x {s(i)} = \int_0^x s(i)di$.

Why could I not represent the cumulative number of fatalities as $\int_0^x \frac{f(u)}{100}du = \frac{365^2}{265}(1 - e^{-\frac{2.65}{365}x})$, where $x$ is in days? [Or when we take $t$ in years, it would be $\frac{365^2}{265}(1 - e^{-2.65t})$.]

Note that the answer provided in the book of total number of fatalities is $-\int_0^t g'(x)dx = g(0) - g(t)$, which also makes some sense to me, as it is the cumulative difference in total population. However, I would think that is undercounting the total number of fatalities, because newcomers could cancel out some of the fatalities. The [existing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/742102/942378) does not help me understand that.

Thanks!

Comment: Your reasoning appears to be correct. Sometimes authors can outwit themselves, especially over longer time spans, or something gets overseen in the editing process with some larger rewrite.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! The problem is that I might have outwitted myself, because what I wrote would be correct if the $f(x)$ was a step function, but since it's not, I don't think anymore my solution is correct. Therefore, I would appreciate if you could write a correct answer (or at least justify why my suggestion above is correct, despite $f(x)$ not being a step function).

Comment: Let's take a simpler problem. Let the population at each day be $f(x) = 2x$. Let the number of fatalities each day be 50% of the population on that day, i.e. $u(x) = x$. As far as I see, at the end of the 4th day, there would be total of 10 fatalities, which is not $\int_0^4 u(x) dx = 8$ but rather $\sum_{i=0}^4 u(x) = 10$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the last. Do you mean $f_0(x+1)=f_0(x)+2$ without fatalities? Then you would get $f(x+1)=0.5·f(x)+1$ with the fatality rate. But depending on the timing of the additions and fatalities it could also be $f(x+1)=0.5·f(x)+2$ or anything in-between.So the number of fatalities in each step is $0.5·f(x)+1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! I thought to simply set up the problem in a more high level way, where I could really just say what the population and the fatality rate is [e.g. at the end of each day]. There are definitely some subtleties which make the simple formulation much more complicated if we need to define it precisely, but my point was that the cumulative number of fatalities on discrete days is the sum of the fatality number function, and not the integral. To get the number of fatalities at each instant in time, we just need to interpolate the sum. What do you think?

Comment: It really depends on the interpretation of the given data. With this small number of individuals, one can not realistically approximate births and fatalities as continuous, constant rate processes. If one assigns times to these events, the result depends on this assignment. If the times are stochastic à la Poisson processes, then the total number of fatalities will likewise be stochastic variable. The differences should not be too large, but they exist. For the integral "Riemann sum" should suffice as argument, the changes in each day are small enough that this gives a valid approximation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! It would be nice if you can just provide that as the full answer, so I can close this question as answered. (I suppose with "Riemann sum" argument you are justifying why I used the integral instead of the sum when computing the cumulative number of fatalities.)